# How to write mocha test for a function with callback function as argument and returns a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, mocha.js

I am trying to write a unit test to following function with callback function as argument and it returns a promise. Control not able to enter into callback method while executing the unit test

```
function addToCache (cacheProxy, policy, cacheObj, req) {
  const logger = global.logger;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    cacheProxy.put(policy, req, cacheObj, function (error, response) {
      if (error) {
        console.error("some error occurred while adding object");
        reject(error);
      } else {
        if (response && response.statusCode) {
          console.log(`got a valid response with responseCode ${response.statusCode}`);
          resolve(response);
        } else {
          console.error("status code missing in response");
          reject(response);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Here is the unit test that I wrote but control not enters inside anonymous callback method defined in cacheProxy.put method argument.

```
describe("mediator tests", function () {
  it("addToCache", async () => {
    const cacheProxy = {
      put: function (policy, req, cacheObj, callback) {}
    };
    medicator.addToCache(cacheProxy, "dummy_policy", "123456789012", {}).then((result) => {
      expect(result.statusCode).to.equal(200);
    });
  });
});
```

I hope someone may help me.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `async` function as your mocha test.
When using `async` you don't need to use the Promise workflow using `.then`.
A `async` function itself returns a Promise automatically.

Instead you have to `await` the Promise result inside your function:

```
describe("mediator tests", function () {
   it("addToCache", async () => {
      const cacheProxy = {
         put: function (policy, req, cacheObj, callback) {}
      }
      const result = await medicator.addToCache(cacheProxy, "dummy_policy", "123456789012", {})
      expect(result.statusCode).to.equal(200)
   })
})
```

Mixing both concepts will most likely not deliver the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the yields for the callback.

```
describe('Verifying retuned data from addToCache', ()=>{
    it("Check Account function's return data should be object from api side",  async function(done){
        this.timeout(configKapsule.unit_testing.timeOut);
        let put = sinon.stub(cacheProxy, 'put')
        put.withArgs(sinon.match.any, sinon.match.any, sinon.match.any).yields(JSON.parse(response))
        cacheProxy.put("policy", "req", "cacheObj", function(result){
            expect(result).to.be.a('object');
            done();
        });
        await medicator.addToCache(cacheProxy, policy, cacheObj, req).then(result => {
            expect(result).to.be.a('object');  // In case of success response
        }).catch((error)=>{
            // in case of error
        })
    });
});
```